# Multiplication symbol in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm importing several CSV files into my MySQL table to populate it. A couple of the files have multiplication symbols in their rows, like: 4×14mm. The import keeps failing when it encounters these symbols, so as a temporary solution I have just replaced them with the letter x, like: 4x14mm. This solution is passable, but I'd really like a proper multiplication symbol if possible. Is this possible?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks Tim!

Comment: I was having trouble with jQuerty rendering these elements after they have been retrieved from the db (not sure why) so rather than changing the char-set to try to handle them, I just replaced them with '&times;' which did the trick nicely.